# Python Multiprocessing Queue file descriptor

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I wanted to know if the queue had a file descriptor and how to find it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Queue` class uses a unidirectional [`multiprocessing.Pipe()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe) for its communications.

You can get either end of that pipe through the connection's (private) `._reader` and `._writer` attributes, and (on POSIX at least), these have `.fileno()` methods:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
>>> queue._reader.fileno()
3
>>> queue._writer.fileno()
4
```

Let me emphasise the 'private' moniker there; the `._reader` and `._writer` attributes are implementation details and thus can be changed future versions without breaking the published API. Use at your own risk.

Comment: The [`fileno()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Connection.fileno) method is always present, but on non-POSIX OSes it could return a process handle instead of a file descriptor. By the way, I'd emphatize more that the usage of `_reader` and `_writer` is an implementation detail, and there is no guarantee that it will work in the future.

Comment: @Bakuriu: That's what I meant with the `(private)` moniker there, I'll emphasise it more. Glad to see a confirmation that Windows has the `.fileno()` method for unidirectional pipes too (all I see in the source is that `win32.ConnectNamedPipe()` is used, and I am not familiar with that call).

Comment: thank you very much, I am just wondering why this is not documented on the python website for this stuff, i have a strong grasp of programming and can write python code to do most things I need but its the advance things that are not documented which I can never find.

Comment: @WojonsTech: it is not documented because it is not part of the official API. You need to go code diving for that instead. The Queue API is meant as a higher-level communication object, the authors did not expect you to *need* access to the file handles.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understand that they did not think i was going to need it but when you really think about it, people sometimes will use java over python because java is "more powerful" but in fact python has all sorts of extra neat tricks it can do like java, but since they dont put it in the docs its hard for people to find out, while the java docs have almost everything in them.

Comment: @WojonsTech: unlike Java, Python is easy to introspect. You can run `dir()` on just about anything, `dir(Queue())` reveals the `._reader` and `._writer` attributes. By documenting those attributes they would be pinned down for future versions to have to support, now the *implementation* is free to change that as needed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i do agree it would take them a lot longer to document it, but would also think they had some auto documenting, in the sense they have the dir(function/class) and just output it so we at least know its there and then for the ones they dont want to document, we can compunity document